# My files are automatically Check out every time I drag and drop from the explorer (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, drag-and-drop, file-explorer

When I drop a document into my SharePoint library from file explorer, it is automatically Checked out.

If only these two conditions apply. Properties are required, or it is a PDF document.

I don't use any web browsers, just using file explorer.

Thanks.

Comment: There’s a library setting may cause the problem. Please go to Library settings > Versioning settings > Require Check Out to see if you have enabled “require documents to be checked out before they can be edited”. If so, please disable it to see the result.